# Applescript transform date format

Tags: applescript, time

I'm using this to transform my date from a DD/MM/YYYY to MM/DD/YYYY

```
set today to short date string of (current date)
set t to (time string of (current date))
set [_day, _month, _year] to [day, month, year] of date today

set _month to _month * 1 --> 3
set _month to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & _month) --> "03"
set the text item delimiters to "/"
set today to {_month, _day, _year} as string
set fullDateToday to today & " " & t as string
```

> e.g 04/20/2019  >  11/15/18

Although how can I transform the year in YY instead of YYYY ?

Comment: Ok not sure why I add an question it just so obvious :
set _year to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & _year)

Comment: You can use the edit function above the comments here to make changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***NOTE:*** I took what was described in a comment and converted it to an answer for completeness on this Q&A.

To convert the date so that the year is in YY format vs. YYYY format you could use this line to set `_year`.

```
set _year to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & _year)
```

#### Example

Here's a full example of the your AppleScript snippet:

```
$ cat showdate.sh
#!/bin/bash

osascript <<END
set today to short date string of (current date)
set t to (time string of (current date))
set [_day, _month, _year] to [day, month, year] of date today

set _month to _month * 1 --> 3
set _month to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & _month) --> "03"
set _year to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & _year)
set the text item delimiters to "/"
set today to {_month, _day, _year} as string
set fullDateToday to today & " " & t as string
END
```

And when it's executed we get the following.

*Today's date*

```
$ date
Sun Apr 21 00:21:08 EDT 2019
```

*via AppleScript*

```
$ ./showdate.sh
04/21/19 00:20:45
```

#### How it works

This AppleScript line:

```
set _year to text -1 thru -2 of ("0" & _year)
```

When executed, will set the variable `_year` to the last 2 digits of the contents of `_year` prior vale. So if the value was 2019, the above line would result in `_year` being 19.

- `("0" & _year)` - converts `_year`'s contents to a string by prefixing a `0` to the beginning
- `-1 thru -2 of ...` - will slice the last 2 digits from `_year`, and remove everything else from `_year`
- `-1` starts indexing from the right instead of the left

#### References

- [Index » unScripted » Dates & Times in AppleScripts](https://www.macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24737)

Comment: @Kevin sure thing, thanks for the Q it was fun to figure out.